# How to add condition in routers of angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My routes are :-

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'alert/:id', component: AlertDetailComponent },
{ path: 'alerts', component: AlertsComponent },
{ path: 'dashboard', component: EriskDashboardComponent },  
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }, 
{ path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },  
];
```

I want that if local Storage contain `token_id` then ./login redirect to EriskDashboardComponent

Comment: You could add a [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#can-activate-guard) guard to the `login` route. Inside the guard, check localStorage and redirect appropriately. Check out the doc, they have code examples and everything.

Comment: can you explain it?

Comment: You can check condition in the guard and then navigate imperatively to an alternative route `this.router.navigate(...)`

Comment: I've posted a full-fledged answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#can-activate-guard) guard in your `'login'` route:

```ts
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [CheckToken] }
```

Inside the guard (named `CheckToken` in my example), check localStorage and redirect the user:

```ts
// check-token.service.ts
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router }    from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class CheckToken implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  canActivate() {
    const myToken = ...; // check localStorage
    if (myToken) {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: code not run it gives error Class 
'CheckToken' incorrectly implements interface 'CanActivate'.
  Types of property 'canActivate' are incompatible.

Comment: My code is not supposed to run verbatim... I just provided it as a blueprint. Please check out the documentation for a full, working example (hint: the canActivate method must return something).